# Lower bound on the eigenvalues of the Laplacian

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, matrices, eigenvalues, spectral-graph-theory

I am looking for a graph for which $2 d_{i} < \mu_{i}$, for some index $i$, where $\mu_{1} \leq \mu_{2} \leq \dots\leq \mu_{n}$ are the eigenvalues of the Laplacian matrix $L(G)$ and $d_{1} \leq d_{2} \leq \dots \leq d_{n}$ are the node degrees.

According to the literature and existing upper/lower bounds on the eigenvalues of the Laplacian as a function of node degrees, it seems 
there is a graph with this property. However, I was not able to find such a graph by generating all graph with $4, 5, \dots, 10$ vertices. 
Any help or advice for a possible hypothesis confirmation or rejection would be appreciated.

Related references:

- Miriam Farber, Ido Kaminer, [Upper bound for the Laplacian eigenvalues of a graph](https://arxiv.org/abs/1106.0769), June 2011.
- A. E. Brouwer, W. H. Haemers, [A lower bound for the Laplacian eigenvalues of a graph—proof of a conjecture by Guo](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/f10a/e559b9ff043ef0492df8f15722b3d16a1bd8.pdf), February 2008.

Comment: There is no example of such graphs. For this, you can use min-max theorem  and the restriction to the subspace generated by vectors supported in first $i$ vertices of the graph.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an expanded solution based on the comment of @mostafa.

Such graphs dose not exist.

Let $L$ be the Laplacian of the graph. Suppose that diagonal elements of $L$ are sorted
sequence of degrees $d_1\leq \ldots \leq d_n$. 
 By [Min-Max theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem#Min-max_theorem), we have

$$\mu_i= \min_{U<\mathbb R^n,\dim(U)=i} \big\{ \max_{x \in U, \|x\|=1} x^TL x \big\}  $$

So, if there exists an $i$-dimensional  subspace of $\mathbb R^n$, say $U$, such that

$$
\max_{x \in U, \|x\|=1} x^TL x \leq 2d_i
$$
then we have $\mu_i \leq 2d_i$.

Let $U := \langle e_1,\ldots,e_i\rangle$, where $e_k$ is $k$-th element of the standard base of $\mathbb R^n$, for $k=1,\ldots,i$. Suppose that $x\in U$ and $\|x\|=1$. Note that only first $i$ elements of $x$ are nonzero. we have
$$
x^TL x = \sum_{ab \in E(G),a<b} (x_a-x_b)^2 \leq \sum_{ab \in E(G),a<b} 2(x_a^2+x_b^2)=2\sum_{k=1}^id_k x_k^2\leq2d_i.
$$
Now the statment at hand.